# Effecient accessing webcam and piping stream to device driver with python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, linux-device-driver, performance

I need to pipe my camera stream to a device driver on an ARM running ubuntu. Now i was wondering if could do this more effecient in python. I first accesst each element and use .open(). But was really not effecient. Now i just run this program and pipe it to a device driver (or file). But i was wondering if i could this more efficient with python? I don't think this will give me 25fps on my arm processor using this code. I ran a few tests, and only got like 7fps.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv 
import sys
import os

camera_index = 1
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
def repeat():
    global capture
    global camera_index
    global count
    frame = cv.GetMat(cv.QueryFrame(capture))
    framegray = cv.CreateMat(480, 640, cv.CV_8UC1)
    cv.CvtColor(frame, framegray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
    sys.stdout.write(framegray.tostring())
    #cv.ShowImage("Webcam", framegray)
    c = cv.WaitKey(40)
    #pipe_out.close()
    if c == 27:
        sys.exit()
    #waitkey kan executitijd van bv dingen ervoor aftrekken


while True:
    repeat()
```

Comment: Have you timed things to figure out what takes the longest?  Getting rid of WaitKey(40) seems like an obvious solution to make it run faster :)  I am suspicious that sys.stdout.write() might be taking most of your time.  Do you have to transfer your data that way?

Comment: Also is there a reason you are using cv instead of cv2 and numpy?

Comment: I used cv in the past and don't have expierence with cv2. Do you think it would improve performance if i used cv2? I use sys.stdout.write() because it transfers the data faster to the device driver then .open(). I'll run a few test tomorrow to test the diffrence. I just want to transfer the data from the webcam as gray image as fast as possible to the device driver with python.

Comment: I don't really know if your performance would go up.  I haven't ever used cv for anything.